# Is it possible to use custom resolution for Macbook Pro with Intel HD 4000?

Tags: macbook-pro

I have a 13" Macbook Pro with Intel HD 4000 chipset and I am wondering, if it is possible to set it use higher resolution then 1280 x 800?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it is not possible. The screen is what is limiting the resolution.

That does mean that you can set up and use an external monitor with higher resolution as you can read on: http://www.apple.com/macbook-pro/specs/

Comment: thanks for the quick reply. Do you happen to know what is the maximum supported resolution by the Intel HD 4000? In other words what is the largest resolution I can get with an external display. I tried to check the hardware specs on the link you gave me but there is nothing there...

Comment: The card itself can handle up to 2560 * 1440. But the max display resolution is once again limited by something else: the outgoing port. Generally you would not be able to go higher then 1920 * 1080 with any other solution then using a DisplayPort-cable to hook up to your monitor.

Answer (score 2):

yes it is possible i am sporting 1440 x 900 res using switchresx

Comment: Great tip, thanks! Is it stable for you?